# Saving a picture into memory

Tags: android, file, memory, storage, photo

I need to use the device camera to take a picture, save it into its memory and get the uri so I can email it afterwards.

I'm using Android 3.2 on a device with no memory card (just 11 gigs of internal storage).

```
    private void takePicture(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
       if(requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
           picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           pictureView.setImageBitmap(picture);

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "Picture");
           values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "picture_ID");
           values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "");
           values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

           pictureUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
           OutputStream outstream;

           try{
               outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(pictureUri);
               picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
               outstream.close();
           }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
   }
```

Any help from someone more experienced with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep something in memory you'd just declare a variable or data structure to hold it; in this case some form of a byte array seems promising. I don't think that would work very well in this case, though. The heap in Android is usually capped at 16 or 25 mb, and depending on what else your app is doing storing photos would get to an "Out of Memory" exception quickly.

So with no SD card, this leaves you with writing to internal storage. I don't know which, if any, directories on internal storage the app can write without root access and/or mounting the system read/write, but I think the best bet is /data/tmp. See if you can save the pic there. If not, mounting the system read/write isn't so bad either.